# ssh connection closed by remote host Centos 7

Tags: centos, ssh

I'm trying to connect via ssh to my server, but connection is failing.

I opened terminal and typed this:

```
ssh -vvv -p 21 root@xx.xxx.x.xxx
```

Here below the log file with results

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.xxx.x.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.x.xxx [xx.xxx.x.xxx] port 21.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/davide/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm newbie for unix terminal so I don't know how I could solve this.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure the target SSH port is right ? `21` is the default port for FTP and `22` is the default for SSH.

Then, if the port is correct, as it is not the default value, I suppose you have another way to access the server. If so, try to follow the recommandations from http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification (the first result when you type `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` on Google).